# EmailConfiguration for AWS cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using cognito to manage users. Following guide of AWS, I have to configure EmailConfiguration.SourceArn like this:

`arn:aws:ses:{region}:{account_id}:identity/noreply@example-domain.com`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration-sourcearn for more details!

Can I set the email address as `SomeApp <noreply@example-domain.com>` ? It'll display "SomeApp" label instead of "noreply" label in users' inbox, which is more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you have to set value for both properties - `SourceArn` and `From`.

Read more about [From property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration-from).

`EmailConfiguration` block will be like (yml syntax):

```
EmailConfiguration:
  ...
  SourceArn: "arn:aws:ses:{region}:{account_id}:identity/noreply@example-domain.com"
  From: "SomeApp <noreply@example-domain.com>"
  ...
```

Comment: I've tried it before and got an error message **"Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in EmailConfiguration: "From", must be one of: SourceArn, ReplyToEmailAddress, EmailSendingAccount"** 

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.update_user_pool
I'm using boto3 client library and it's documentation still mentions From. It's weird. I may try to debug this library.

Thanks

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen Hmmm, check again your lib version, the boto3 requires a lib called `troposphere` (https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere), it has a issue reference to your issue https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/issues/1538 (closed)

Comment: I tried latest version of boto3 on local and it works. Now, I am waiting for deployment process. If there aren't no errors, the issue may be resolved.